# css sticky footer without scrollbar

Tags: css, layout, footer, sticky-footer

How to do to avoid having the scroller with a sticky footer to the bottom of the page (not bottom of window)? 
When I remove height=100% from content and sidebar, I'm no more getting the scroller. However, when doing so, my content and sidebar do not fill all the space down to the footer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 13</title>
<style media="all" type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body, #wrap, form {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap, #footer {
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrap {
    background: #cff;
}
html, body {
    color: #000;
    background: #a7a09a;
}
body > #wrap {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
form {
    /*height: auto;*/
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    background: #000;
    height:100%; 
    min-height:100%; 
    height: auto !important; */
}

#content {
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 570px;
    background: #9c9;
}
#sidebar {
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    background: #c99;
    padding: 10px;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px; 
    height: 100px;
    clear: both; 
    background: #cc9;
    bottom: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
#header {
    /*padding: 5px 10px;*/
    background: #ddd;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="main" class="clearfix">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>header</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <h2>sidebar</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <h2>main content</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <h2>footer</h2>
    </div>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result in both opera 10, IE8 and FF3

Comment: I normally use this: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
I never seem to see any issue with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is finally one solution (I don't remember where I get this code .... it's not mine ;-) ) :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>CSS Layout - 100% height</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%; /* needed for container min-height */;
    background: gray;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    color: #666;
}
div#container {
    position: relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/;
    margin: 0 auto;
/* center, not in IE5 */    width: 750px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    height: auto !important; /* real browsers */;
    height: 100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/;
    min-height: 100%; /* real browsers */
}
div#header {
    padding: 1em;
    /*background: #ddd url("../csslayout.gif") 98% 10px no-repeat;*/
    border-bottom: 6px double gray;
}
div#content {
    padding: 1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
}
div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */;
    background: #ddd;
    border-top: 6px double gray;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        entete  </div>

    <div id="content">
        contenu </div>
    <div id="footer">
        pied de page
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using a container div with a 100% min-height.  Then, I have the page content and footer div's in the container.  Here's my HTML:

```
 <div id="MainContainer">
        <div id="FullPage">
        </div>
        <div id="Footer">
        </div>
 </div>
```

And here's my corresponding CSS:

```
html, body, #MainContainer
{
    min-height: 100%; /*Sets the min height to the height of the viewport.*/
    height: 100%; /*Effectively, this is min height for IE5+/Win, since IE wrongly expands an element to enclose its content.  This mis-behavior screws up modern browsers*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html > body #MainContainer
{
    height: auto; /*this undoes the IE hack, hiding it from IE using the child selector*/
}

#MainContainer
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#FullPage
{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 25px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Footer
{
    clear: both;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code ... but after adding some content the slider appears even if the content is occupying only a part of the window. 
Here is the html I used with your css : 

    <div id="MainContainer">
 <div id="FullPage">
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="Footer">
  <h1>footer</h1>
 </div>
    </div>